# User Edit Page for different elements

Tags: forms, users, 7

I want to customize the user edit page.  I want to separate the elements (eg. user password, user picture, user email) and put them each on a separate edit page.  I tried [the panels module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels), but that only allows me to move the entire form.

Is there a way to separate these form elements on different pages. For instance a change password page, a change user picture page and add the email into an existing user profile edit page?

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two main directions you can go if you want to 'expand' user profiles:

- You can either add fields, field groups and eventually group them in tabs or thelike.
- Or you try the module [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) wgich is basically the successor of the core profile module.

Both approaches can be fruitful – both will let you spread user profiles over different 'pages' (or tabs). But I'm not sure how fine-grain you can actually go with these two approaches – and if you can actually 'diconnect' the *change password* ui from the rest. I usually try to keep the core info on one page – and 'the rest' (contact and bio etc.) on sub-pages (tabs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @tillinberlin. I am using profile2 for all of my fields. But I am not entirely sure how to integrate the drupal password and email fields. I did originally create a 'profile image' profile and used a image field. But I prefer the default drupal profile image for various reasons.